# Getting duplicate count when executing INSERT IGNORE via JDBC

Tags: mysql, jdbc, insert

Is it possible to get the duplicate count when executing MySQL "INSERT IGNORE" statement via JDBC?

For example, when I execute an INSERT IGNORE statement on the mysql command line, and there are duplicates I get something like

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec) 
Records: 1 Duplicates: 1 Warnings: 0

Note where it says "Duplicates: 1", indicating that there were duplicates that were ignored.

Is it possible to get the same information when executing the query via JDBC?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe that duplicate data is stored in the query. Closest thing would be to run a `SELECT` with `WHERE unique values` before the `INSERT`, get number of rows and there's your Duplicates.

Comment: Did you find how retrieve the value of duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can retrieve this by issuing `SHOW WARNINGS` after your insert.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-warnings.html

Comment: INSERT IGNORE does not produse a warning when trying to insert duplicate value. As I wrote before - if I run it from SQL console - it produces something like this: 

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec) Records: 1 Duplicates: 1 Warnings: 0

So "Warnings: 0" means that there is no warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ROW_COUNT() and FOUND_ROWS() functions to determine the number of inserted rows and duplicates when doing INSERT IGNORE.

For Example :

```
SELECT ROW_COUNT(), FOUND_ROWS()
    INTO myRowCount, myFoundRows;
myInsertedRows = myRowCount;
myDuplicateRows =  myFoundRows - myInsertedRows;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: And where is "INSERT IGNORE" in your example?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `rows affected` value via JDBC. Just subtract it from the number of rows you inserted.

Bear in mind that `rows affected` also includes rows that are indirectly affected by the query. So, if there are any triggers that affect other rows, `rows affected` will include those rows as well.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()