# mysql insert ingore : count number of duplicate records that are ignored

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

i am using mysql database and Rails framework. i am doing bulk insert with "insert ignore" sql statment. The query is working fine but i also want to calculate the count of rows that are being ignored or duplicated. i searched a lot for this and found not any blog on the internet.

i was thinking of using `rows_affected` to get the count but it also has drawback as explained here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10150702/2274074

Please help

Comment: Your bulk insert statement will give you the number of rows created. Using that just calculate the difference of rows created and the numbers of objects for bulk insert.

Comment: @AmitThawait - how to get the number of rows created by bulk insert.

Comment: @Hytool -  mysql docs say "SHOW WARNINGS displays information about the conditions resulting from the most recent statement in the current session that generated messages" . So there is no guarantee that result i am getting is for bulk insert statement only.

Comment: @user2274074 How are you doing bulk insert. Using any gem ?

Comment: @AmitThawait : No its just simple insert statement.  "insert ignore into authentication_codes(code) values ('14bdlhq259ji3'),('sdfdsf)"

Comment: So do a count before you start inserting.

Comment: @dan-klasson - but there can be duplicate key so if i insert 2 rows  and there is one duplicate key then only one row will be inserted instead of 2 rows..

Comment: Yeah so you count it before, and then count it again when done and subtract that.

Comment: @dan-klasson - yes that i can do. but i am inserting 1 million records at a time.. and searcing for 1 million records into the database is very bad idea and hence i want to get the count of record after inserting record into the database. i dont want to search into the database to get the count because after one year then can be more than 1 billion entry in my database and searching from this 1 billion entry is time consuming to just get the count.